# Are there any caveats involved in using object.__class__ in python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Are there any caveats involved in using `object.__class__`? for example in Django once I did this:

```
model_object.__class__.objects.all()
```

I would like to know if that's perfectly fine.

Thanks.

Comment: This is fine if you can ensure that `model_object` is really a model object.

Comment: It depends on *why* you want to do his. `model_object.objects.all()` would work the same way, as long as `model_object` doesn't have an instance attribute `objects` that shadows the class attribute.

Comment: @chepner I wanted to do this for the convenience of not having to import the class. Since I already had the object. `model_object.field.__class__.objects.all()` where `field` is a foreign_key field pointing to another Django model. "`model_object.objects.all()` would work the same way." good point I missed that.

Comment: I think that it is better to import the cls instead of use `__class__`

Comment: @WaketZheng how so ?

Answer (score 2):

Explicit is better than implicit. Just import the model class::

```
from .models import ModelClass

ModelClass.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. `<class instance>.__class__` is a reasonable way to get class attributes or methods of an instance. There's usually some better built-in way to interact with dunder attributes and methods though-- In your case you could use `type()` to access `.__class__` instead, e.g. `type(model_object).objects.all()`.